# TypeError: button.classList is undefined

Tags: javascript

How do I fix this error?

What am I doing wrong?

I can't get rid of this error message.

**I changed this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/8gajsp3v/7/

> TypeError: el.classList is undefined"

```
  function getButtonContainer(el) {
    while (el.classList.contains("playButton") === false) {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
  }
```

[image]

**to this:**

Did I do something wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/tg056zv4/

> TypeError: button.classList is undefined"

```
 function getButtonContainer(el) {
    function isPlayButton(el) {
      return el.classList.contains("playButton") === true;
    }
    while (el !== document && !isPlayButton(el)) {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far I undestood your issue

your `el` is pointing to svg or the polygon element that you are clicking. When you click on `div`     `<div class="playButton soundpark">` other then the ICON then classList property is available in the DOM.

So Instead of doing `el.classList.contains("playButton")` you will need to locate the closest div and validate if `playButton` class is available.

So change `el.classList.contains("playButton")`  to `el.closest("div").classList.contains("playButton")` will solve your problem with the error.

Comment: Broken now for other reason. console `el`. you will find the elements as svg and polygon that doen't have class property